# I am doing a project that will calculate the volume, average volume and standard deviation of different containers (cuboid, cylinder, sphere)

Tags: java

I am doing a project that will calculate the volume, average volume and standard deviation of different containers(cuboid, cylinder, sphere)

I wrote a class for each container and abstract class (Shape). In the class that contains the main method, I used arrayList to add each  container, but really the problem I have is that I made a loop to prompt the user which kind of container he/she has and after  response, I can call the right constructor, but after doing everything for first container entered, the loop terminates.

my code of main method is this:

```
import java.util.*;
class testShape
{

   public static void main(String args [])
   throws java.io.IOException
   {

      double total = 0;
      int i,n;
      double deviation,average,sdeviation;
      double sd = 0;
      double s = 0;
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

      ArrayList<Shape> shapelist = new ArrayList<Shape>();

      for(i=0;i<3;i++)
      {

         System.out.println("Enter shape: B for box,C for cylinder, S for sphere ");

         char c=(char)System.in.read();



         if((c=='B')||(c=='b'))
         {


            System.out.println("How many boxes do you have");
            n = sc.nextInt();
            for(i=0;i<n;i++){
               shapelist.add(new Box());
            }
            for(i=0;i<shapelist.size();i++)
            {
               System.out.println("--------"+shapelist.get(i).getShapeName() + "----------"); 
               System.out.println(shapelist.get(i).toString()); 
               System.out.println("The volume of "+shapelist.get(i).getShapeName()+""+(i+1)+" is "+shapelist.get(i).findVolume());  
               total = total+ shapelist.get(i).findVolume() ; 
            }

            System.out.println("-------------------\n");
            System.out.println("the total volume of"+shapelist.get(0).getShapeName()+" is: "+total+"\n");
            average= total/n;
            System.out.println("The average volume of "+shapelist.get(0).getShapeName()+" is: "+average);
            for(i=0;i<n;i++){

               deviation = (shapelist.get(i).findVolume()-average);
               s= deviation*deviation;
               sd = s+sd;
            }
            sdeviation =Math.sqrt(sd/n);
            System.out.println("the standard deviation is: "+sdeviation);
         }


         else  if((c=='C')||(c=='c')){
            System.out.println("How many cylinders do you have");

            n = sc.nextInt();
            for(i=0;i<n;i++){
               shapelist.add(new Cylinder());
            }
            for(i=0;i<shapelist.size();i++){
               System.out.println("--------"+shapelist.get(i).getShapeName() + "----------"); 
               System.out.println(shapelist.get(i).toString()); 
               System.out.println("The volume of "+shapelist.get(i).getShapeName()+""+(i+1)+" is "+shapelist.get(i).findVolume());  
               total = total+ shapelist.get(i).findVolume() ; 
            }
            System.out.println("-------------------\n");
            System.out.println("the total volume of"+shapelist.get(0).getShapeName()+" is: "+total+"\n");
            average= total/n;
            System.out.println("The average volume of "+shapelist.get(0).getShapeName()+" is: "+average);

            for(i=0;i<n;i++){
               deviation = (shapelist.get(i).findVolume()-average);
               s= deviation*deviation;
               sd = s+sd;
            }
            sdeviation =Math.sqrt(sd/n);
            System.out.println("the standard deviation is: "+sdeviation);
         }

         else if((c=='s')||(c=='S')){
            System.out.println("How many Sphers do you have");

            n = sc.nextInt();
            for(i=0;i<n;i++){
               shapelist.add(new Sphere());
            }
            for(i=0;i<shapelist.size();i++){
               System.out.println("--------"+shapelist.get(i).getShapeName() + "----------"); 
               System.out.println(shapelist.get(i).toString()); 
               System.out.println("The volume of "+shapelist.get(i).getShapeName()+""+(i+1)+" is "+shapelist.get(i).findVolume());  
               total = total+ shapelist.get(i).findVolume() ; 
            }
            System.out.println("-------------------\n");
            System.out.println("the total volume of"+shapelist.get(0).getShapeName()+" is: "+total+"\n");
            average= total/n;
            System.out.println("The average volume of "+shapelist.get(0).getShapeName()+" is: "+average);

            for(i=0;i<n;i++){
               deviation = (shapelist.get(i).findVolume()-average);
               s= deviation*deviation;
               sd = s+sd;
            }
            sdeviation =Math.sqrt(sd/n);
            System.out.println("the standard deviation is: "+sdeviation);
         }

         else 
            System.out.println("Invalid selection");


      }



   }  

}
```

Comment: Once you've an answer here, post the solution to [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). You need to refactor your code big time.

Comment: Why are you not reading your first character using the scanner instance that you have instead of `char c=(char)System.in.read()`?